# load iframe googlemaps async

Tags: asynchronous, maps

I'm trying to optimize the loading of the google map on my website, but I'm not familiar with it. Specifically, I generated an iframe but I would like to add the Async tag to it so as not to penalize the speed of the site. to be safe I obscured the api key.
I hope someone can help me

I tried inserting the async tag into the code to no avail. Can anyone tell me how to insert the async tag into this iframe code:

```
<iframe larghezza="600" altezza="450" style="Border:0" load="lazy" allowfullscreen src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=place_id:ChIJIbYkgTheLxMRAo_VsBRHruU&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></iframe>
```